# Google Colab (Python, jupyter notebook) terminal input

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am running .py script with arguments, but the code asks for input and I can not enter anything as seen in the picture.
[image]

Comment: how many times do you have write terminal input ?

Comment: Did you ever get a reasonable answer to this?

Answer (score 3):

**Updated:** Colab now supports input prompts. Try running things again, and you should see a prompt like so:

[image]

Comment: I don't see this on Colab - is there something I'm missing? I'm using the free tier

Comment: The appearance is now different. I updated the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

If you know beforehand what inputs you want to enter then you can use:

`! printf 'y\ny\ny\n' | python run.py --task 1 --gpu -1 --data "data/"`

In above case, if terminal prompts for an input three times, it will enter first y then y then y. `\n` is just for newline.

e.g-

If you need to enter only two input, say `q` followed by `d` then it should look like:

`! printf 'q\nd\n' | python run.py --task 1 --gpu -1 --data "data/"`